# Map UI component is not displayed in Cuba Platform

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cuba-platform

I use [CUBA Platform](https://www.cuba-platform.com/) version 6.0.8 and trying to add map viewer component to the screen, but it's not shown.
Screen descriptor is listed below:

```
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd";
        caption="msg://browseCaption"
        class="com.mycompany.gui.mapsample.MapScreen"
        focusComponent="mapBox"            
        xmlns:chart="http://schemas.haulmont.com/charts/charts.xsd">
    <layout margin="true" spacing="true">
        <vbox id="mapBox">
            <chart:mapViewer id="map" height="100%" width="100%"
                             mapType="satellite"/>
        </vbox>
    </layout>
</window>
```

I followed [this](https://docs.cuba-platform.com/cuba/5.6/charts/en/webhelp/map_project_setup.html) step. These are map properties:

```
cuba.charts.map.freeApiKey = ********************************
cuba.charts.map.clientId =  ********************************   
cuba.charts.map.defaultZoom = 13.0
cuba.charts.map.defaultLatitude = 51.5001
cuba.charts.map.defaultLongitude = -0.1262
```

and here's the controller:

```
public class MapScreen extends AbstractLookup {

    @Inject
    private MapViewer map;

    @Override
    public void init(Map<String, Object> params) {
        GeoPoint center = map.createGeoPoint(53.490905, -2.249558);
        map.setCenter(center);
```

What can be the problem or at least where should I start debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the given link points to the 5.6 version of the manuals, if you work with version 6, please use proper documentation you can find [here](https://www.cuba-platform.com/manual)

Regarding the problem you are facing: it's not an issue of the Map componet, but layout issue. Vbox height is not specified, so adding height="100%" to the vbox should solve the problem:

```
<vbox id="mapBox"  height="100%">
    <chart:mapViewer id="map"
                     height="100%"
                     mapType="satellite"
                     width="100%"></chart:mapViewer>
</vbox>
```

Also, as a useful tip, you can always Analyze Layout while run time and find out what the problem is. To perform this check right click on a tab and press **Analyze Layout** (see the picture below).

[Analyze Layout in runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGiZZ.png)

So, if you analyze layout in your tab you will get the following message:

```
[ERROR] Container 'mapBox', nested component 'map'
Nested component has relative height 100.0% inside container with undefined height
```

which clearly explains where the problem is.

Comment: ohh, I see, I forgot to expand the parent vertical box, tx